# Can't update my firebase version to 16.0.5

Tags: firebase

When I try to update my firebase version to 16.0.5 I get this error:

```
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/protolite-well-known-types/16.0.1/protolite-well-known-types-16.0.1-javadoc.jar'
```

How do you solve this? I have tried updating my android studio version and gradle but without success.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

1) Please check the Firebase [website](https://firebase.google.com/) to see the [latest versions of Firebase's functionalities](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android?hl=pt-br#latest_sdk_versions).

2) Try updating them all to the latest version and try running build again.

3) If this does not help try then to downgrade some of them, one by one.
(I tried today and I saw that this problem is solved when I changed:

> implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3"

to:

> implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2"

as of for today.)

Hope this helps.